# Does GoogleMaps plugin/widget create Google My Business listing?

Tags: wordpress, plugin, google-maps, widgets, google-my-business

I do NOT want a Google My Business listing. I know it's good for local SEO but I don't want to manage reviews.

If I use the GoogleMaps widget on my WordPress website, will that automatically create a Google My Business listing?

GoodTherapy.org automatically displays a GoogleMaps widget/plugin when I enter my work address while making my profile page. Will this create a Google My Business listing I don't want?